# Shell script 'installer'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to create a `--setup` flag for a shell script that makes the script globally executable, so 1. `sudo chmod +x $0` and 2. `sudo cp $0 /usr/local/bin`, or so..

The problem obviously is, that the script won't run until it is executable. Maybe one could call it as `sudo bash ./script --setup`?

Are there any best practices this or making scripts behave more like cl tools installed from official repositories?

Comment: Why isn't the script executable to begin with? How is it distributed?

Comment: As an aside, `$0` isn't reliable as a pointer to a usable path or directory. See [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: If you want something to behave as if it were "installed from official [package] repositories", why not, err, *build a package* for it (for whichever Linux distro you want this behavior)? That way it'll get all the facilities that any other piece of software has: Folks can see if it exists and at what version with `rpm -q` or `dpkg -l` or such; find the owning package with `rpm -Qo` or equivalent, uninstall it automatically, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `install`

```
Usage: install [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  install [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  install [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
  or:  install [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORY...

This install program copies files (often just compiled) into destination
locations you choose.  If you want to download and install a ready-to-use
package on a GNU/Linux system, you should instead be using a package manager
like yum(1) or apt-get(1).
```

or, as it documentation says, build a package for your distro or a [universal snap](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/06/14/universal-snap-packages-launch-on-multiple-linux-distros/).